# dealing with complex GET params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, get, form-for, ransack

I'm trying to pass params via GET to a form using ransack, it would normally work fine except that the params[:q] is causing a problem when I try to merge it.

controller (using [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack))

```
  def index
    @search = Record.ransack(params[:q])
    @records = @search.result.page(params[:page])
  end
```

view

```
<ul>
  <% Genre.all.each do |genre| %>
    <% category_count = @search.result.joins(:genre).where("genres.id = ?", genre.id).size %>
    <% unless category_count == 0 %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to genre.name, params.merge(:"q[genre_name_eq]" => genre.name) %> (<%= category_count %>)
        </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But I keep getting duplication:

```
q[genre_name_eq]=Rockabilly&q[genre_name_eq]=Rockabilly
```

Without the q[] it manages the params correctly, overwriting the previous one.

Also tried `params[:q].merge(:genre_name_eq)` which causes the problem when there is no q[] and it also just doesn't work, giving me `genre_name_eq=` and no q[]

How else can I handle the q[] so that it replaces the value instead of duplicating it several times?

Comment: Can you paste the params and the params.merge(:"q[genre_name_eq]" => genre.name) ?

Comment: ok, updated with more details.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (after your edit)

`params` is a hash, not a simple querystring. If you want to update a nested value, you have to update the nested hash.

First ensure that `params[:q]` exists and is a hash (in the controller)

```
params[:q] ||= {}
```

Then only update `q` in the view

```
<% params[:q].update :genre_name_eq => genre.name %>
<%= link_to genre.name, params %>
```

Comment: that works great with one set of params, but when used in conjunction with another set of params, say `q[record_format_name_eq]` it always chooses the last one (of genre), even when nothing has been selected.